# Passing arguments inside URLfetchApp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the below script to call data from Spreadsheet,
But I face error showing "Exception: Invalid argument:" in log

```
function myFunction() {
  
const key = "606503c07f32a32677df7e0f"
const ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const wsLocation = ss.getSheetByName("Location")
const wsLiveData = ss.getSheetByName("Live Data")

const location = wsLocation.getRange("A2").getValue()
const units = wsLocation.getRange("B2").getValue()

const highCell=wsLiveData.getRange("B4")
const lowCell=wsLiveData.getRange("C4")

let apiURL= 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${location}&appid=${key}&units=${units}'

const resText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL).getContentText()
console.log(resText)

}
```

Please help me to call location, units and key in **apiURL**. Currently I called using ${location}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the single quotes in the apiURL with back quotes:

```
`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${location}&appid=${key}&units=${units}`
```

and see if that helps?

Comment: Hello JPV
Thanks, It works.